# Fetching a single table data in nested style in Laravel

Tags: laravel, group-by, fetch, distinct

I am asked to load data from a single table like the following:

```
    =================================
    |id |dept | response | created_at |
     =================================
    |1  |FO   | GOOD     | 2018-05-20 |
    |2  |FO   | GOOD     | 2018-05-20 |
    |3  |IT   | GOOD     | 2018-05-20 |
    |4  |FO   | BAD      | 2018-05-20 |
    |5  |IT   | GOOD     | 2018-05-20 |
    |6  |LO   | BAD      | 2018-05-20 |
    |7  |IT   | GOOD     | 2018-05-20 |
    |8  |IT   | GOOD     | 2018-05-21 |
    |9  |LO   | GOOD     | 2018-05-21 |
     =================================
```

they want me to display only records created_at 2018-05-20. and the desired output display in blade is like this:

```
 FO
    GOOD    2
    BAD     1
 IT
    GOOD    3
    BAD     0
 LO
    GOOD    0
    BAD     1
```

when I use select distinct, it displays only one row of response data (only `GOOD`). The same thing happens when I use `groupBy`

here are my current codes:

Controller:

```
$date =  new Carbon('2018-05-20');

$result = Result::select('dept', 'response')->where('created_at', '=', $date->toDateString())->groupby('dept')->get();
```

blade:

```
 @foreach($result as $result)
    {{$result->dept}}</BR>

    {{$result->response}}</br></br>
@endforeach
```

The output I get:

```
 FO
 GOOD    

 IT
 GOOD    

 LO
 GOOD
```

I don't do the `count` yet because I still get this undesired result.
Is there a way to achieve the desired request with that single table?

EDIT I:
Based on `Yrv16's` answer, my controller goes like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Result;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index()
{

$date =  new Carbon('2018-05-20');

$results = Result::select('dept', 'response', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
      ->where('created_at', '=',$date->toDateString())
      ->groupby('dept','response')              
      ->get();

$results = $results->groupBy('dept');
return view('result.index', compact ('results'));
}
```

and my blade:

```
@foreach($results as $result)
{{$result->dept}}</BR>

    {{$result->response}}</br></br>
@endforeach
```

this gives me an empty page. but when i change this `where('created_at', '=', $date->toDateString())` to `where('created_at', '>=', $date->toDateString())` i get this error `Property [dept] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupBy` for two columns `dept`, `response`:

```
$date =  new Carbon('2018-05-20');

$results = Result::select('dept', 'response', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count'))
          ->where('created_at', '=',$date->toDateString())
          ->groupby('dept','response')              
          ->get();
```

Also result collection you can `groupBy('dept')` in order to display it like you want:

```
$results = $results->groupBy('dept');
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($results as $dept => $result)
    {{$dept}}</BR>
    @foreach($result as $item)
        {{$item->response}} {{ $item->count }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: it gives me this error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View...`

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi change your `@foreach` it uses $result in two places. Change for `@foreach($results as $result)`.

Comment: i've changed it and the same thing happened. I tried @Leon Vismer's answer below, it works but i have no idea how to pass it to `@foreach()` loop

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi His query will be slower because he do all manipulations with help of laravel collections (In my case - with help of DB). Show your foreach code

Comment: I edited my post and put my foreach there in Edit I section.

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi Show full controller method, not only query.

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi `$result` is collection and you need loop it,too.

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi I added blade for my answer.

Comment: now i get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: if i use this `$results = $results->groupBy('dept');` i get `Property [dept] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: i have another question. is it possible to calculate subtotal for each group? like FO has 2 `good` response and 1 `bad`, so the sub total would be 3.

Comment: @DaddiAlAmoudi use new variable  inside first loop = 0 and then in second loop make sum (for example $sum += $item->count;).

Comment: i put the variable in controller or in blade?

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection manipulation for that:

```
$results = Result::where('created_at', '2018-05-20')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('dept')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        return $item->groupBy('response')->map(function ($responses) {
            return $responses->count();
        });
    });
```

It will give you the following results:

```
print_r($results->toArray());

Array (
[FO] => Array (
        [GOOD] => 2
        [BAD] => 1
    )
[IT] => Array (
        [GOOD] => 3
    )
[LO] => Array (
        [BAD] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: i get the array in view but i have no idea how to display those arrays in `@foreach()`